# File system: Kernel calls vs. Caching

Tags: linux, file, caching

I would like to write a file manager for educational purposes. I'm planning to split the software to a backend and a frontend. The backend would do file system caching like this:

1. User double-clicks the directory `/foo/bar` in the frontend
2. Backend receives file list query from front-end on path `/foo/bar`

   - Reads the file entries from disk at `/foo/bar` using `readdir()`
   - Stores the entries in data cache server (Redis)
   - Returns the results to the frontend
3. Frontend displays the file list in `/foo/bar`

The next time a user wants to list files from `/foo/bar` the backend would return entries from the data cache server instead of doing disk I/O through kernel calls, assuming that files in `/foo/bar` didn't change since the last query - which I can monitor using something like `inotify`.

Now, my questions are the following:

1. Does this architecture make sense, or the Linux kernel/file-system/etc. already takes care of caching?
2. Is the overhead of communicating with a Redis server worth it when working with a lot of files, versus the disk I/O of listing directory contents?

Comment: Does not make sense to me. Number of system calls to get data from Redis is higher than to get it from kernel cache.

Comment: True that, but you get to avoid disk I/O.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Does this architecture make sense, or the Linux kernel/file-system/etc. already takes care of caching?

Linux does take care of caching to some extent and it is mostly related to loading files in memory (which are not written to). Also depending on LINUX to cache your directories means that you loose control over what gets to be cached. Further more, LINUX caching is depending on many factors since it's cache's goal is primarily to ensure data consistency and not read performance.

So it does make sense to offload some of the work from the disk.

> 2. Is the overhead of communicating with a Redis server worth it when working with a lot of files, versus the disk I/O of listing directory contents?

This raises more question. Is the disk located on a separate machine or a local machine and also where would the Redis server be located. Is it a clustered environment or a simple server?

If Redis and the disk are on the same & single machine then the you'll have to bare the cost of network no matter the end location is. When you're inside the machine, RAM always beats Disk I/O whether read or write.

For more information see this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/238417/are-networks-now-faster-than-disks)

> #### Numbers Everyone Should Know
>
> ```
> L1 cache reference                             0.5 ns
> Branch mispredict                              5 ns
> L2 cache reference                             7 ns
> Mutex lock/unlock                            100 ns (25)
> Main memory reference                        100 ns
> Compress 1K bytes with Zippy              10,000 ns (3,000)
> Send 2K bytes over 1 Gbps network         20,000 ns
> Read 1 MB sequentially from memory       250,000 ns
> Round trip within same datacenter        500,000 ns
> Disk seek                             10,000,000 ns
> Read 1 MB sequentially from network   10,000,000 ns
> Read 1 MB sequentially from disk      30,000,000 ns (20,000,000)
> Send packet CA->Netherlands->CA      150,000,000 ns
> ```

Comment: There are options to control Linux's level of caching. Look at sysctl vm.vfs_cache_pressure for example.

Comment: True but wouldn't it affect the whole Linux system usage and not just the required entries. If OP could benchmark it.

Comment: Thank you. I came to the conclusion that I will have to do some benchmarking before I can decide whether or not it is worth the effort. I will probably implement both in the prototype of my file manager and see the results for myself.

Comment: Good decision and I'm glad I was able to help :)

Comment: Do post your finding please!